# how to add maps to a list dynamically?

Tags: grails, groovy

As I described in the question I want to add maps to a list dynamically, and avoid to add map with the same key I am trying this

```
def myList = []
["a", "b", "c", "c", "d", "e", "f", "a" ,"f"].each { letter ->
   def map = [:]

   //here I want to check if current letter exist as key in myList
   //if it is true then avoid next code

   map.put(letter, [])
   myList << map
}

println myList
```

In the real life scenario letter will be inputs added by user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here You go:

```
def myList = []

["a", "b", "c", "c", "d", "e", "f", "a" ,"f"].each { letter ->  
   if(!myList.find { it.keySet().contains(letter) })
      myList << [(letter): []]
}
assert myList ==  [[a:[]], [b:[]], [c:[]], [d:[]], [e:[]], [f:[]]]
```

Or You can simply:

```
def myList = ["a", "b", "c", "c", "d", "e", "f", "a" ,"f"].unique().collect { [(it):[]] }
assert myList ==  [[a:[]], [b:[]], [c:[]], [d:[]], [e:[]], [f:[]]]
```

Comment: @Opal hehe, sorry about that...completely missed your followup

Answer (score 2):

Using `find` on your `List` and `containsKey` on the `Map` instance will accomplish what you are looking for. The documentation for [Maps](http://groovy.codehaus.org/JN1035-Maps) has more information.

```
def myList = []

["a", "b", "c", "c", "d", "e", "f", "a" ,"f"].each { letter ->
  def map = [:]
  if (!myList.find{ it.containsKey(letter) }) {
    map.put(letter, [])
    myList << map
  }
}

println myList​ // [[a:[]], [b:[]], [c:[]], [d:[]], [e:[]], [f:[]]]
```